# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child, using a conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display the list of results taken from the response of wikipedia API.
If the response doesn't show any list, it should show a different message. I am trying to do a conditional rendering.

Here is the code:

```
getData(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var search = e.target.search.value;
        var wikipediaEndPoint = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&origin=*&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max&gsrsearch="+search;
        var wikipediaUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=";

        fetch(wikipediaEndPoint)
        .then(data => {
            return data.json();
        }).then(data => {
            var objectList = (data.hasOwnProperty("query")) ? data.query.pages : "";
            let resultList;

            if(objectList !== ""){
                resultList = Object.keys(objectList).map(function(key, index) {
                    return (
                        <div className="item" key={objectList[key].pageid}>
                            <a href={wikipediaUrl+objectList[key].pageid}>
                                <h1>{objectList[key].title}</h1>
                                <p>{objectList[key].extract}</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    )
                });
            } else {
                resultList = (function() {
                    return (
                        <div className="item" key={1}>
                            <p>No results!</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                });
            }

            this.setState({search: resultList});
        })
    }
```

The result is shown here: `<div className="items">{this.state.search}</div>`

It works fine when the search field keyword finds some results, however, on the opposite case the console returns an error (or a warning):

> `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if`
>   `you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe`
>   `you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Where is the error? Am I doing the conditional rendering the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
            resultList = (function() {
                return (
                    <div className="item" key={1}>
                        <p>No results!</p>
                    </div>
                )
            });
```

Why are you setting a function? Just set the `<div...` -

```
            resultList = (
                    <div className="item">
                        <p>No results!</p>
                    </div>
                )
```

**Edit -**

In order to really use a function (not sure why, though), the code would have to be a bit different -

```
            const Foo = (function() {
                return (
                    <div className="item" key={1}>
                        <p>No results!</p>
                    </div>
                )
            });
            resultList = (<Foo />)
```

**Edit 2 -**

The above edit works because React components do not have to be constructors/classes, they can also be a simple function that gets props as a parameter and returns JSX. I think this type of components is a bit limited, but it works.

Answer (score 5):

you're setting `resultList` to a function when `objectList === ""`.  either return a `<div>` directly, or else use that function as an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
resultList = (function() {
  return (
    <div className="item" key={1}>
      <p>No results!</p>
    </div>
  )
})(); // note the parens here, which call the function
```